# Problems after changing turbo

Tags: mercedes-benz, turbocharger

Im desperate for some help. I recently had my turbo changed on my Mercedes C200 diesel after the shaft broke. After the change I have had a problem that will not go away. It occasionaly over and underboost, overboost to a point where i blew the pressure hose that goes from the intercooler, after I changed it it with a new hose ripped the housing the hose goes into apart, meaning serious pressure. On the other hand, sometimes it underboost. If i go fast and then come to a stop and start in frist gear it feels like it’s not boosting at all and crawling away with 1/3 of the power, if I then let go of the gas and give gas again the boost is back and goes like it should. After the turbo change, I have changed hoses from intercooler, I have changed the intercooler, several sensors but nothing works. Next step is changing the turbo once more, rather not go there if there is something else, I can do. Any help would be highly appreciated.

BTW im on my 4th mechanic now, they tell me every time now it’s fixed and I pay them in the thousands and hope not so far no luck.

Hope to get help

Best Nicolai

Comment: I would have suggested taking it back to the mech who fitted the turbo - but since you took it to 3 others plus did work yourself that is no longer possible... Have you checked the operation of the boost control system - pipes, mechanism free movent etc

Comment: And wastegate, and the associated controls?

Comment: What about the boost pressure sensor, have you had that checked?